# How to send error validation message from controller to the view in Laravel 5.2

Tags: php, laravel-5

Code in my **PagesController.php**

```
public function postIndex(Request $request){

    $this->validate($request, [
            'name' => 'required',
            'email' => 'required|email',
            'phone' => 'min:3',
            'message' => 'min:10',
    ]);

    $data = array(
            'name' => $request->name,
            'email' => $request->email,
            'phone' => $request->phone,
            'bodyMessage' => $request->message,
            'subject' => 'Some subject',
    );

    Mail::send('emails.contact', $data, function($message) use ($data){
        $message->from($data['email'], "Hello");
        $message->to('some_user@gmail.com');
        $message->subject($data['subject']);
    });

    Session::flash('success', 'Email was sent');

    return redirect('/');
}
```

In the `$request` are data from form inputs. If some errors are in validate view is redirect to '/'.

My question is how to handle error message in view ?

Comment: I see it very clearly at https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/validation#other-validation-approaches... Just read

Answer (score 0):

```
Session::flash('success', 'Email was sent');
// this will set messages in session

return redirect('/');
// this will redirect to the given url
```

and on the view you can show these messages like:

```
if(Session::has('success'))
{
     echo '<div class="alert alert-danger">'. Session::get("success").'</div>';
}
```

Note: Session::flash() messages will remain active for one request only.

Answer (score 0):

In your view to show [validation error](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/validation#quick-displaying-the-validation-errors) you can add following code in the blade file:

```
@if (count($errors) > 0)
  <div class="alert alert-danger">
      <ul>
          @foreach ($errors->all() as $error)
              <li>{{ $error }}</li>
          @endforeach
      </ul>
  </div>
@endif
```

**Update**

One reason can be that `web` middleware is applying two times in your case. Laravel by default adds web Middleware in `app/Providers/RoutesServiceProvider.php` and again you are adding it in your routes.php
Try it by removing `web` middleware from your routes.php.

Comment: Problem is that when I try print $errors in view trere is nothing.

Comment: I have not Middleware in my routes.php